# Problem with heatmaps in Google Fusion Tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

These are my two functions for searching my table and making overlays. (the map is created in a different function). For some reason, the dotmap one works fine, but the heatmap one doesn't work with the where clause. Any insight?

```
function heatmap() {
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'LOCATION',
            from: '1614684',
            where: "CRIME = 'HOMICIDE'"

          },

          heatmap: {
            enabled: true
          }
        });

        layer.setMap(map);
}
function dotmap() {


    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'LOCATION',
        from: '1614684',
        where: "CRIME = 'HOMICIDE'"

      }
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the same as mentioned here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/MkZ8KJT6oic

In short, Heatmaps in Google Fusion Tables is a little flaky. You might want to use something like [gheat](http://code.google.com/p/gheat/) which somehow worked, but not as nice and simple as I wanted.

Comment: This example looks great: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-fusiontables-heatmap?hl=nl
But I am not seeing any heatmap data at all using this exact example and sheet reduced to only a few hundred rows.